# How to create a user-based file upload storage system in PHP and MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, file, cloud, storage

It will be user based; user can store file by uploading it to database/server.
Just like little cloud, user can view files anytime after logging in.

How can I make a start on the implementation? I need to store files as per user account, can't plan for database implementation.

Created demo layout (screenshots)

### Screenshot pics

#### 1.[image: User Login]

#### 2. [image: User Panel]

#### 3. [image: Uploaded Files]

Comment: It'll really be of benefit if you could start something. At the very least, make an attempt.

Comment: Start with making a login page. Of course you should set up database tables.

Comment: ohh yeh.... planing though *_*

Comment: have some other stuff related to this

Comment: You have to use below steps -
1) Create the directory structure for your project
2) Setup the plain html pages [You can use any on the template from web]
3) Create the database
4) Code login, upload, list, download

Here is the video tutorial for same-
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XdqpkaufmEA

Comment: Ohh Thnx Man...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### This Worked For ME

You have to use below steps -

1) Create the Directory Structure for your project

2) Setup the plain HTML pages [You can use any on the template from web]

3) Create the Database

4) Code Login, Upload, List, Download

Here is the Related  video Tutorial -  [YOUTUBE](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XdqpkaufmEA)    by  – **Mata Prasad Chauhan**

Answer (score 0):

if you start at least something from scratch it would be best . 
follow the below tips when you want to start it . 
first make a home page with login and sign up form . 
then redirect login user to upload and create form there . 
and when they upload something redirect to their uploaded page . 
you can follow the below simple tutorials to create uploading system in php . 
Visit https://davidwalsh.name/basic-file-uploading-php

Comment: well thnx...I'll check 

but how to implement file storage for
 different user ...I mean  separate db table for files for each user accounts ^_^